# Missing index at:: 2

Tags: java, stored-procedures, oracle-adf

I'm trying to call a SQL procedure from my ADF aplication.

I have the following code in my AppModule:

```
public void callProcedureSimulateFromDB(String idCategoria) {
    CallableStatement cs = null;
    System.out.println("categoria-> " + idCategoria);
try {
    cs = getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("begin ? := SPSIMULATE(?); end;", 0);

    cs.setString(2, idCategoria);
    cs.execute();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new JboException(e);

} finally {
            if (cs != null) {
                try {
                    cs.close();
                }catch (SQLException e) {}
            }
        }
}
```

And this is in my backing bean, where I'm calling the previous method:

```
public String simulate() {
    String categoria = catIdId.getValue().toString();
    if (categoria != null && !categoria.isEmpty()) {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application app = facesContext.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory elFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
        ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
        ValueExpression valueExp = elFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{bindings}", Object.class);
        oracle.binding.BindingContainer binding = (oracle.binding.BindingContainer)valueExp.getValue(elContext);
        OperationBinding operationBinding = binding.getOperationBinding("callProcedureSimulateFromDB");

        // Set the Input parameters to the operation bindings as below
        operationBinding.getParamsMap().put("idCategoria", categoria);

        // Invoke the Application module method
        operationBinding.execute();
        // Get the result from operation bindings
        //Object obj = operationBinding.getResult();
        //System.out.println("obj ----> " + obj);
    }
    //ADFContext.object.applicationModule.myAMMethod() ;
    //chamar funçao da DB
    p55.hide();
    return null;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I've tryed changing de callable statement and the number in the `cs.setString()`. However, the problem stays the same.

EDIT:
After making some changes to the code, I tested the AppModule and got the following error:

```
(oracle.jbo.JboException) JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: java.sql.SQLException, msg=ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case SPSIMULATE is a stored procedure (and not a stored function), you can try changing this line:

```
 cs = getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("begin ? := SPSIMULATE(?); end;", 0);
```

To

```
  cs = getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement("{call SPSIMULATE(?)}", 0);
```

And make sure you test your procedure from BC Tester before caling it from backing bean. Smaller steps are always faster.

Comment: Not working, either way, but the error changed http://puu.sh/gyrft/db45c05976.png

Comment: Are you testing from BC tester?

Comment: I wasn't but I get the same error there, but a longer description